# Lie groups generated by finitely many Lie algebra elements

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. A standard fact is that $G$ is generated by $\exp(\mathfrak{g})$, i.e. every $g \in G$ can be written as $g=\exp(x_1)\cdots\exp(x_n)$ for some $x_i\in\mathfrak{g}$. A natural follow-up question is whether there is a bound on the number $n$ of Lie algebra elements. I suppose this depends on the group, so let me formulate my question as follows.

**Question.** *What are natural conditions on a Lie group $G$ which imply that there is a finite number $n$ such that
$$G = \underbrace{\exp(\mathfrak{g}) \cdots \exp(\mathfrak{g})}_{n \text{ times}}?$$
For instance, is this true for complex semisimple groups?*

Of course, there are many cases in which $\exp$ is surjective (e.g. $G$ compact or nilpotent) so that $n = 1$.
I'm looking for a larger class of groups, preferably in the linear algebraic category, or just interesting specific examples where $n > 1$.

Comment: Are you aware of any examples where there isn't such $n$?

Comment: In every example I know, the image of the exponential contains a dense open set. When this occurs, every $z$ can be factored as $\exp(\mathfrak{g}) \exp(\mathfrak{g})$, since this is the same as showing that $\exp(\mathfrak{g}) \cap z \exp(\mathfrak{g})^{-1}$ is nonempty, and an intersection of two dense opens is always nonempty. But I am not sure how generally it is true that $\exp(\mathfrak{g})$ contains a dense open.

Comment: In $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, the image of the exponential does not contain a dense open -- any matrix with distinct negative eigenvalues (equivalently, trace $<-2$) is not an exponential. However, I believe it is still true that every matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a product of two exponentials, so this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: In a Cartan subgroup of a connected complex semisimple group, it is clear you get everything in one exponential. By density of conjugates, you get a dense image in one exponential.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

$\def\fg{\mathfrak{g}}$The following answer is a paraphrase of material from

*Philips, Christopher N.*, [**How many exponentials?**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2375057), Am. J. Math. 116, No. 6, 1513-1543 (1994). [ZBL0839.46054](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0839.46054).

We'll say that a Lie group $G$ has **exponential rank** $\leq k$ if every element of $G$ is a product of $\leq k$ exponentials.

We'll say that $G$ has **exponential rank** $\leq k+\epsilon$ if the set of products of elements $\leq k$ exponents is dense in $G$. In other words, in a group of exponential rank $\leq k+\epsilon$, for any open neighborhood $\Omega$ of the identity, we have $G = \exp(g_1) \exp(g_2) \cdots \exp(g_k) u$ for $g_1$, $g_2$, ..., $g_k\in\fg$ and $u \in \Omega$. Since it is known that $\exp(\fg)$ contains an open neighborhood of the identity, any group of exponential rank $\leq k+\epsilon$ also has exponential rank $\leq k+1$. We define the exponential rank of $G$ to be the minimum $r$ in  $\{ 1 < 1+\epsilon < 2 < 2+\epsilon < 3 < \cdots \}$ such that $G$ has exponential rank $\leq r$.

Note that, if $G = AB$ (for Lie subgroups $A$ and $B$) and the exponential ranks of $A$ and $B$ are $(a,b)$, $(a+\epsilon, b)$, $(a, b+\epsilon)$ or $(a+\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$, then the exponential rank of $G$ is bounded above by $a+b$, $a+b+\epsilon$, $a+b+\epsilon$, $a+b+\epsilon$ respectively.

In this vocabulary, Phillips proves (Section 5) that

- Connected compact groups have exponential rank $\leq 1$.
- Unipotent groups have exponential rank $\leq 1$.
- Connected complex groups have exponential rank $\leq 1+\epsilon$. This bound cannot be improved, because $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ has exponential rank $1+\epsilon$ (the matrix $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} -1&1 \\ 0&-1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ is not an exponential)).
- Connected solvable groups have exponential rank $\leq 1+\epsilon$. This bound cannot be improved: Consider the Borel $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} z & u \\ 0 & z^{-1} \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ inside $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and the same matrix as before.
- All connected Lie groups have rank $\leq 2+\epsilon$.
- $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ has exponential rank $2$.

The proof that all connected Lie groups have rank $\leq 2+\epsilon$ is credited to Djokovic: The point is that any connected $G$ has an Iwasawa decomposition $K(ANR)$ where $K$ is compact connected (so exponential rank $\leq 1$) and $ANR$ is connected solvable (so exponential rank $\leq 1+\epsilon$).

Phillips states it as an open problem whether there is a connected Lie group of exponential rank $2+\epsilon$, or whether, in fact, exponential rank $2$ is always enough.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449294/14094), Phillips' 1994 question (whether in every connected Lie group every element is a product of 2 exponentials) has been solved positively by Wüstner in 2003. By the way, Wüstner seemed unaware of Phillips' question since he didn't quote his paper.

Comment: For completeness: any matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ with two distinct negative real eigenvalues, e.g. the matrix $-\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\1 &1\end{pmatrix}$ or $-\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\0 &1/2\end{pmatrix}$, is not in the closure of the image of the exponential map (to justify that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ doesn't have exponential rank $\le 1+\epsilon$).

Answer (score 5):

In any real connected Lie group, every element is the product of at most two exponentials.  This is proved in "[A connected Lie group equals the square of the exponential image](https://www.emis.de/journals/JLT/vol.13_no.1/14.html)" by Michael Wüstner in the Journal of Lie Theory, Vol. 13, No. 1, pp. 307--309 (2003).