# Which Lie groups admit finite generation by a set of Lie algebra elements? And what are some known choices of generators which realize this?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Consider a (finite-dimensional) real connected Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\frak{g}$. Take a generating set $\mathcal{G} = \{ X_1, \cdots X_n \} $ of $\frak{g}$, i.e. such that any element of $\frak{g}$ can be written as a linear combination of their nested commutators.

Any element in $g\in G$ may be written as a, possibly infinite, product of elements in the one-parameter subgroups of $\mathcal{G}$,  $ g =  e^{t_1 X_{i_1}} \cdots e^{t_k X_{i_k} } \cdots$.

For $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ all possible *minimal* generating sets have been characterized and the order of generation computed (this is the minimal number $N$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^N e^{t_i X_{i_N}}$ cover all of $G$). Namely, this number is finite (and not smaller than 4) as long as the generators are not all "compact". If we treat this group/algebra as a matrix group/algebra, this condition is equivalent to not all generators having imaginary eigenvalues.

Is there a condition on a Lie group $G$ which determines whether there exists a finite set of $\{X_i\}$ such that the "minimal sequences" necessary to obtain any $g\in G$ are finite, in the case that $G$ is connected semisimple (non-compact, otherwise I think this is a well known result)? Can one compute the minimal number of generators and corresponding "length of generation" $N$ for any such Lie group?

Assuming $G$ satisfies the above condition, are there some known necessary and/or sufficient conditions which determine whether a given set $\{ X_i \}$ will finitely generate $G$ in the meaning above?

What are some examples beyond $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$? I'm especially interested in the simple classical Lie groups $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C}), \operatorname{SO}(n,\mathbb{C}), \operatorname{Sp}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: A first question is whether this minimum is finite. For instance (a) I think $G$ has finite center iff there exist such $X_i$ so that the min is finite. (b) If $G$ has finite center, for given $(X_i)$ I think this min is finite iff there exists $i$ such that the 1-parameter subgroup $(\exp(tX_i))_t$ is not contained in any compact subgroup.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a reference for your second statement? It seems to be exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't exactly have a reference. If you edit your question to clarify that this is exactly what you're asking, I'll be happy post an answer with more details.

Comment: I have modified the question. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: I've posted an answer proving (b) in the semisimple case. In the above comment, I was too bold stating (a): even in the infinite center simple case, the min can be finite. However, it can be infinite even when one of the 1-parameter groups has noncompact closure.

Comment: Maybe not duplicate but certainly very closely related: [Lie groups generated by finitely many Lie algebra elements](https://mathoverflow.net/q/416754/41291)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm specifically interested in a choice of generators given by one-parameter subgroups, which to me seems much more specific than the exponential of the entire Lie algebra.

Comment: For a complex connected algebraic group, the Bruhat decomposition and the Zariski density of the big Bruhat cell reduces the problem to unipotent groups and split tori, where the answer is easy. And Bruhat decomposition holds even for connected component of a real algebraic group; this covers many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a connected simple Lie group with finite center. Let $S$ be a generating subset of $G$ (symmetric with $1$) such that $S^n$ has nonempty interior for some $n$ (this is automatic if $S$ is $\sigma$-compact, by the Baire theorem). In the paper "[On lengths on semisimple groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01001)" (J. Topol. Anal. 2009) I proved the following: either $G=S^N$ for some $n$, or $S^k$ has compact closure for all $k$.

(In the paper it is stated equivalently in terms of lengths: every locally bounded length is either bounded or proper. For the word length relative to $S$, "locally bounded" means that $S^n$ has nonempty interior for some $n$, bounded means $S^N=G$ for some $n$, proper means each $S^k$ has compact closure for each $k$.)

Let $X=(X_1,\dots,X_p)$ be a generating family of the Lie algebra, generating 1-parameter subgroups $$P_i=\{\exp(tX_i):t\in\mathbf{R}\}; \qquad S_X=\bigcup_{1\le i\le p}P_i.$$ Apply the above to $S=S_X$. Then we see that either $S^N=G$ for some $N$, or $S^k$ has compact closure for all $k$. In the second case, all $P_i$ have to have compact closure. In the second case, assuming $G$ non-compact, we deduce that for some $i$, $P_i$ has a noncompact closure.

> In other words, when $G$ is a noncompact simple Lie group with finite center, the minimum which you define is finite if and only if there exists $i$ such that $\exp(\mathbf{R}X_i)$ has noncompact closure.

When $G$ is semisimple with finite center, I think one can show something similar: namely, if $T_j$ are the noncompact simple factors of $G$ (view them as quotients of $G$), then for each $j$ there exists $i$ such that the projection of $\exp(\mathbf{R}X_i)$ to $T_j$ has noncompact closure. (I guess this follows from Proposition 1.6 of the above reference.)

I'm not sure what happens beyond these (important) cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also wondered about the computation of such a minimum, are you aware of a way to compute such a minimum (or to upper bound it, possibly in relation to the dimension of the group, maybe just for the classical simple Lie groups)? If not, I will still accept the answer, since it addresses my main question.

Comment: It won't be less than the dimension of the ambient Lie group. Anyway, even for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ I don't know if the answer is $3$ or more, and how it varies with the choice of 1-parameter subgroups. There is the $KAK$ decomposition, which already says the answer is $3$ for some choice.